# Proof about monotonicity of functions

Tags: functions, derivatives

> Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$
>
> Suppose $f'(x)>0$ for all x $\in (a,b)$
>
> $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $and $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$
>
> $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $and $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$
>
> Show $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$.

---

What i tried so far:

Let $x_1,x_2 \in (a,b)$,

Assume $x_1<x_2$

By MVT exist $c$ in $(a,b)$ s.t. $f'(c) = \dfrac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}$

With $f'(c)>0$ implies $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$

That $f$ is strictly in creasing on $(a,b)$

Also WTS for all x in (a,b), $f(a)<x<f(b)$

That is $f(a)<x$ and $x<f(b)$

Assume its negation is true

Have $f(a)\geq x$ or $x \geq f(b)$

Now need to find some contradiction

...

Any help would be appreciated.

Please tell me if there is an easier proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is finished with the the line that begins "With $\;f'(c)>0\;$ ..."! Nevertheless, I would write it down as follows:

Take any two *different* points $\;x_1,\,x_2\in [a,b]\,,\,\,x_1<x_2\;$ ( of course, it can be $\;x_1=a\;$ or $\;x_2=b\;$). Since the conditions of the MVT are fulfilled in $\;[x_1,x_2]\;$ , there exists

$$\;c\in (x_1,x_2)\;\; s.t. \;\;\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}=f'(c)\stackrel{\text{given!}}>0\;$$

Since $\;x_2-x_1>0\;$, we get that *it must be* $\;f(x_2)-f(x_1)>0\implies f\;$ is mon. ascending.$\;$ Q.E.D

Answer (score 0):

If $x>a$ then $f(x)-f(a)=\lim [f(x)-f(a+\frac 1 n)] \geq 0$. If $f(x) =f(a)$ then there exists $c \in [a,x]$ such that  $f'(c)=0$ but this contradicts the hypothesis. Hence $f(a) <f(x)$. Simialrly $f(x) <f(b)$ if $x <b$.